# Executing TestNG tests with different parameters set in @BeforeClass method

Tags: java, parameters, testng

I want to test some code with different persistence units. Therefor I have written two identical TestNG test classes that only differ in the name of the persistence unit that I pass  to `Persistence#createEntityManagerFactory` to get the correct factory.

This call is in a setup method annotated with `@BeforeClass``

```
@BeforeClass
public void setupClass() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-eclipselink-h2");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    // init with some dummy data

    // ... some more initialization
}
```

What are the options to execute this test class with different persistence-units? It would be sufficient to have the names hardcoded in test classes, there is no need to specify them externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A {
    private String s;

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] dp() {
        return new Object[][] {
          new Object[] { "test-eclipselink-h1" },
          new Object[] { "test-eclipselink-h2" }
        };
      }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public A(String s) {
        System.out.println("Creating test class with " + s);
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `The annotation @Factory is disallowed for this location` - but it looked promising

Comment: You must be using an old version of TestNG.

Comment: Yes, the version is quite old... I'll try with the latest one and convince the project owner to upgrade ;)

Comment: Great. Changed the maven dependency to the most recent version and it works like a charm. Thanks!